# Installing a module in Python

Tags: python, python-curses

I wanted to install the curses module in python but I always get this issue :

```
PS C:\Users\#####\Desktop\Python> pip install curses
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses
```

I am still new in coding and this is my first time using Stackoverflow
Please help :(

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pip install windows-curses
```

ref: [this](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/)

or might use `pip3` if running python3

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install windows-curses` as you are using windows. Default `curses` module does not support windows.

Comment: when I did what u told me a message appeared      "Successfully installed windows-curses-2.2.0"      I thought it worked but when I started working in vs code it said 
           "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'" :(

Comment: How are you importing this? See that it is `windows-curses` not `windows_curses` and I am not sure but they don't support `python3.8 and +` yet from PYPI wheels. So, maybe it is not compatible with your python version.  I would suggest you open an issue [here](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses) for more explicit and specific support related to this with all your errors and environment details.

Comment: I write it using copy and paste from your comment. My Python version is v2021.10.1336267007 so maybe it is a version issue

Comment: Check python version using `python -V` or `python --version` and report it to your issue on the project repository that I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `windows-curses`
https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/
*Good Luck ;-) Best Regards !*

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Comment: I tired it but this message keeps appearing   "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'"  :(

Comment: @ Feras Which OS, pip and python version you have installed? By the way, this error occurs when using this module rather than installing with pip ??? Maybe you got it wrong?

Comment: Deducing you installed the package correctly, you just have trouble using it...

Comment: Windows 10, python v2021.10.1336267007 and I don't know what pip version I am using I don't even know how to know it.
when I tried  pip install windows-curses  it said Requirement already satisfied but I still get the no module issue

Comment: @Feras To check pip version => type in cmd "pip --version"  To check python version => type in cmd "python --version" :-))